# A running stable JAR file of JOGL 2.0?

Tags: java, opengl, jar, jogl

I'm looking for a running **stable** JAR file of JOGL version 2.0 .

I've searched in the jogl website [here](http://jogamp.org/) , but I can't find a stable version with only a JAR file and its DLL files .

Can someone please point out which one is the stable version from [here](http://jogamp.org/deployment/autobuilds/master/)  or [here](http://jogamp.org/deployment/archive/rc/) , since there are so many ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Go to: http://jogamp.org/deployment/v2.0-rc11/archive/

Download the `jogamp-all-platforms.7z` file and extract it. In the `jar` directory you will find all of the good stuff.